# Java tree, returning parent node recursively

Tags: java, loops, recursion, tree

I was working on some task about returning parents node out of tree.
The tree looks like this:

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   /    /
  4    5
      / \
     6   7
```

It has some constrain that the class node doesn't have method that can return the parent node. So we need to create our own method to get the parent node. Here is my method:

```
public Node getParentNode(int idChild, Node pParent) {
    List<Node> child;
    List<Node> gChild;
    if (pParent == null)
    {
        child = root.getChildren();
    } else {
        child = pParent.getChildren();
    }
    Node nParent = null;

    if (child != null) {
        for (Node c : child) {
            if (c.getId() == idChild) {
                nParent = c;
                break;
            } else {
                return getParentNode(idChild, c);
            }
        }
    }

    return nParent;
}
```

Somehow it works to retrieve the parent of node with id 4, which is node with id 2. But when it comes to retrieving parent node for node with id 5, 6 and 7 it didn't work. So basically it is only work for node with id 2, 3, and 4.

Can someone pointed out what I've been missing with the recursion or the loop? Since I am not really good at it.

Comment: Can Node class be extended to keep the reference to the parent node?

Comment: *Curious:* What is the point of `gChild = c.getChildren();`? What is the point of `else {/*do nothing*/}`?

Comment: What you're trying to do should be a "depth first search". You need a Stack of some sort or else it isn't going to work. Try to look up some algorithm online to do this question.

Comment: @HongyuWang The code *is* a "depth first search". The code is using recursion which *is* "a Stack of some sort". Perhaps you should look at the code before commenting.

Comment: @Andreas that was a mistake, deleted already. To be fair, it is a sudden question that has to be done using java, i dont have the compiler, just compile it online

Comment: @BullocktaBodax You should always develop your code locally in an IDE, especially if you're new to Java. The IDE will help you with syntax errors, auto-completion, javadoc, debugging, etc. so doing it without is handicapping yourself. StackOverflow is not a replacement for doing the work yourself, e.g. the debugging part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
return getParentNode(idChild, c);
```

You shouldn't just return the result of this call as it is. What if the node you are searching for is not in that subtree. You should return only when it returned a non-null result (else the *for* loop won't loop to the next child node)

Return only if you found a parent node in the recursive call.

Also, there is a mistake in the return statement in the `if` block. You should return the reference to the parent node and not the current child node.

```
 {
     ....
     if (child != null) {
         for (Node c : child) {
            gChild = c.getChildren(); //Btw this is just dead store
            if (c.getId() == idChild) {
                return pParent; //You want to return the parent not the current node.
            } else {
                nParent = getParentNode(idChild, c);
                if (nParent != null) {
                    return nParent;
                }
            }
        }
    }  
    return null; //Node (idChild) not found in this subtree
}
```

Comment: You should also fix the first part, i.e. replace `nParent = c;` with `return pParent`, and replace `return nParent;` with `return null;`